# How do I get subfolders to show in a dropdown?

Tags: html

I'm just learning html to build a team site at work. I'm getting the hang of it pretty easily, but I'm having an issue with subfolders not showing in a dropdown. The html is linked to css for a design, but I know the problem isn't with the css.

I'm not exactly sure what to try as I mentioned I am just learning how to code the html.

```
<li class="top"><a href="#nogo4" id="hsolinks" class="top_link"><span class="down">Folders</span></a>
<ul class="hsolinks">
    <li><a href="#" target="_parent" class="hsolinksfly"><span class="down">HIPAA Security Office</span></a></li>
        <ul class="hsolinks">
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Access</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Audit</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">LAN File Access</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Training</a></li>
</ul>
```

The expected result is that the folders "ACCESS", "AUDIT", "LAN FILE ACCESS", and "TRAINING" would show under the HIPAA Security Office in a css dropdown. However, when I place the code into SharePoint it only shows an arrow, but no folders in the dropdown under HIPAA Security Office.

Also, there is additional code under this which is why I have only closed one ul tag. I hope I'm clear with what I'm trying to do!

Comment: PS - Just a tip for the future. Pull any explicitly identifiable information from your examples, we don't need to see your internal file structures you're using in your hrefs or any PII for that matter to help your issues. My first glance at this thing was "HIPAA Security" and I damn near spit out my coffee...

Comment: @ChrisW. Okay! Thanks for the heads up! I'm still learning haha I've been working on this for maybe just a few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<li>` element always needs to be surrounded by a `<ul>` element. But you can have a `<ul>` inside an `<li>` if needed. Something like so will work

```html
<ul>
    <li class="top">
        <a href="#nogo4" id="hsolinks" class="top_link">
            <span class="down">Folders</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="hsolinks">
            <li>
                <a href="#" target="_parent" class="hsolinksfly">
                    <span class="down">HIPAA Security Office</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="hsolinks">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">Access</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">Audit</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">LAN File Access</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">Training</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

For more information and examples about the `<ul> <li>` elements read: [ul: The Unordered List element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)

Comment: Thank you! This was a major help!